# Как из меню вынести флажки языков в хедер в мобильной версии?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

В мобильной версии флаги перевода сайта на другие языки прячутся в мобильное меню и их не видно. Как их вынести из меню и расположить рядом с кнопкой меню в мобильной версии?

Получилось сделать это в веб-инспекторе, но как это сделать на самом сайте. И в десктопной версии видно флаги из мобильной. Как их скрыть?
[image: Десктопная версия]

[[image: Мобильная версия][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cftip.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот код... нельзя смешивать логику с внешним видом

Comment: У меня получилось в веб инспекторе переместить флаги, но проблема в том, что они и в мобильной и в десктопной версии. А надо сделать так, чтоб в десктопной их не было видно. Но как это сделать?